# The main theorem of discrete Morse theory.

Tags: general-topology, morse-theory

[image]
I  don't understand this part of the proof on page  16 of the following paper.
[http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/forman5.pdf](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Eaar/papers/forman5.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

By the assumption of the theorem, there are no critical values between a,b. But notice that according to the negation of (i) which you quoted, it follows that $\tau$ is a critical cell. Since its value is greater than that of $\sigma$ and it does not belong to [a,b], it has to be greater than b.

To see the deduction from Lemma 3.2, you can use induction on the dimension of $\tau$. Finally, the intersection is empty by the definition of $M(a)$ (Def. 3.1).